# For a nonlinear regression task, is either Maximum Likelihood Estimation or Least Squares easier to learn a neural network model with?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, maximum-likelihood, least-squares

I have data `(x,y)` and I want to create a model `f(x)` that will best approximate `y`. Let's assume that my data may not have homoscedasticity and the relationship between `x` and `y` is definitely nonlinear, so I want to use a neural network model for this regression task.

I know Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) and Least Squares (LS) are sometimes equivalent, and could both be used here. However, I don't know which would be the better tool to use for this, practically.

If I were to naively implement LS, for each `x`, I'd have it output a `y'` and then minimize the sum of squares `(y - y')**2`.

If I were to naively implement MLE, for each `x`, I'd have it output a `mu_y', sigma_squared_y'` and then maximize the log likelihood of `y` under the normal distribution `normal(mu_y', sigma_squared_y')`.

Is one of those generally easier to find a better solution with? For example, MLE requires outputting more (therefore requiring a larger network), but I can also imagine it being less brittle than LS to large errors.

**To be clear, I am *not* asking about the *equivalence* between MLE and LS with the assumption of Gaussian noise.**

Comment: Are you sure you are really doing MLE when you train a neural network?

Comment: MLE is a very general procedure for writing down functions which are *maximized* to find optimal parameters given the assumptions of a certain likelihood function. As you've pointed out, some models assume a fixed variance component $\sigma^2$ for all of the data (OLS), while some other models estimate a variance component for each observation $\sigma_i^2$ by some method. So as it's stated now, it seems that you're asking when to use two alternative models, each of which makes different assumptions about your data. Is this your question? Or are you asking something else? (If so, what?)

Comment: All else being equal, it's easier to estimate one thing (the mean) than two things (the mean and the variance). But these models aren't equal, so it seems that  you're asking how to compare apples and oranges.

Comment: @microhaus if the objective is maximizing the log likelihood for the whole dataset, why wouldn't that be MLE?

Comment: @Sycorax I see what you mean, so I edited it to make the question clearer. I'm asking about the general case of approximating a nonlinear function with a neural network, when the data doesn't necessarily have homoscedasticity.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that there is a distinction between the standard parametric point estimation setting of finding an estimator that achieves the global maximum of the log-likelihood function; with that of training a neural network. In the latter case, even though you set up the optimisation problem to maximise the conditional log-likelihood, you rarely, if ever find a global maximum of it. Rather, your "maximum likelihood estimator" consists of a set of weights for which prediction error on a held-out data set is acceptable.